# angular2 + bootstrap + data-toggle="tab"

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, tabs

I stuck with stupid problem. 
I have the following code:

```
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span12">
                    <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#tab-1" data-toggle="tab">Details</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#tab-2" data-toggle="tab">Images</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#tab-3" data-toggle="tab">Paints</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#tab-4" data-toggle="tab">Manual</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="tab-content" #tab >
                        <div class="fade tab-pane active" id="tab-1">
                        </div>
                        <div class="fade tab-pane" id="tab-2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="fade tab-pane" id="tab-3">
                        </div>
                        <div class="fade tab-pane" id="tab-4">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

If i have p tag with id - it works fine. 
But I have tabs. I reviewed a lot of examples and questions for SoF but nothing works for me. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You might want to check native Bootstrap widgets for Angular 2 to make your life easier: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabs

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource well first of all I'm not sure I understand why it is broken. there is very simple logic - add/remove style class to tag. why it is broken inside angular?